# Convert List<A> to List<B> without having two copies C#

Tags: c#, database, list, memory, garbage-collection

I have a list (`List<A>`) in C# which is consistently around 900MB in size.
When converting this list to another type (`List<B>`, for inserting into a database), I iterate over each element to add it to the new list.

This is using a lot of RAM, so I was wondering whether there's a way to transform that list to the new type without using any extra RAM?

At this stage I've thought of iterating over `List<A>`, transforming it to `List<B>` in batches of say 100000 elements, setting `List<A>` elements to null and forcing a garbage collection might be a way to do it.

Due to database IO performance issues, and the specifics of how `List<A>` is implemented, doing this conversion whilst inserting into the database is not possible.

Do you guys have any ideas for a nice way to do these sorts of operations?

Comment: Hard to say without the knowledge why you need `List<B>`. Away from that I would iterated over `List<A>` and `yield return` every item which will be processed and set to `null`. This way you would free your ram on every single item while it is being send to the database.

Comment: @C4ud3x, I would do this if I could, but inserting entries into the database 1 by 1 takes too long. I'm using SqlBulkCopy to insert data.

Comment: Ah I see. So you need to format your data so it fits the process to insert it into SqlBulkCopy. Then I cant tell anything bettern than Matthew did in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A` and `B` are classes, and you have a `public static B Transform(A a)` method to convert an `A` into a `B`, I'd do it like this:

```
List<A> aList = new List<A>(); // Assume this list is populated.

var bList = new List<B>(aList.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count; ++i)
{
    bList.Add(Transform(aList[i]));
    aList[i] = null;
}

// If aList is a local it will go out of scope and its remaining
// memory will be freed. If it is not local, you must ensure that
// all remaining references to it (if any) are set to null.
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I thought something like this might be the best way to do this. I tried this solution just then, but I wasn't able to set aList[i] to null - because it's provided through an API, and the API has it set to readonly. Any other ideas?

Comment: @aleksk Hmm well if you can't change the original list then your options are limited. If class `B` is serialisable, you could serialise the converted data to a disk file and then delete the original list before deserializing the converted data. That's likely to be very slow, but it will use much less memory. But if you're not running out of memory, why do you need to worry about it in the first place, even if it is using a lot of RAM temporarily?

Comment: That's a good idea. At this stage, we've decided to split the data up into different subsets and perform the bulk copy on these subsets. We were actually getting OutOfMemoryExceptions though. Thanks for your help.